# Uncaught reference error: Firebase is not defined when using with phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, dom, firebase

I have the following html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Current Tour</title>
    <!-- cordova -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- jquery -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <!-- firebase database -->
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js'></script>
    <!-- current_tour.js -->
        <script src="../js/current_tour.js"></script>

    <h1>Current Tour</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and following javascript

```
var trip_id;

function onDeviceReady() {
    alert('device ready');
    var fb_id_ref = new Firebase('https://trip- chronicle.firebaseio.com/'+window.localStorage.getItem("fb_id"));
    console.log("**DEBUG**: Connected to firebase");

    var facebook_id = fb_id_ref.name();

    fb_id_ref.on('child_added', function(childSnapShot){
    console.log("**DEBUG**: fireBaseRef.on()");
    trip_id = childSnapShot.ref();
    alert(trip_id);
    });
}    

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

If I create some button and call *onDeviceReady* with button *onclick* event, it works fine. But, if I try to call *onDeviceReady* with event listener  *deviceready* I get this error: *Uncaught reference error: Firebase is not defined.*

Comment: It's worth noting that Firebase has a library specifically for PhoneGap: http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/04/16/firebase-phonegap-integration/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deviceReady` indicates that the *PhoneGap* API is ready, not that your external JavaScript has finished loading ( http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html ).

Instead, you should use the traditional [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/load?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMozilla_event_reference%2Fload) event.

Comment: How can I check if external javascripts has loaded.

Comment: The `load` event will fire when they've been loaded.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/load?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMozilla_event_reference%2Fload